# What is Special VFR? Why would a pilot request it?

Tags: visual-flight-rules, special-vfr

I have heard about Special VFR many times but never understood this concept. What is it and when is it used?

Comment: Heeeey. Stop closing questions I can answer :D @fooot

Comment: @SentryRaven go answer one of the duplicate targets instead :)

Comment: To be honest, I don't even think this is a duplicate. The other questions are already a bit more specific coming from someone who understands what SVFR in general is, but wants clarification on finer points. This question here asks what SVFR is for to begin with...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Special VFR is used to leave or enter a control zone coming from or continuing the flight in airspace G (Golf), when the weather minima for VFR flight are not met within the control zone, but would be met in airspace G.

Example: Airspace G (Golf) requires a visibility of 1.5km and aircraft need to remain clear of clouds. Airspace D (Delta) requires a visibility of 5km and 1000ft vertical and 1.5km horizontal separation to clouds.

If the weather report would show a visibility of 4km/4000m and a cloud base of 1400ft, the flight would be allowed in airspace G but not in airspace D.

Requesting Special VFR within a control zone will drop the VFR weather requirements to the values required for airspace G, so flight may enter or leave the controlzone. The lower visibility requirements are compensated for in the control zone by stricter separation requirements between aircraft. SVFR is separated to SVFR and IFR traffic.

Comment: For comparison: In the US class D VFR minimums are 3 sm vis and 500/1000/2000 feet below/above/horizontal clearance from clouds.  The difference from class G minimums are only during the day, when class G has 1 sm visibility required and clear of clouds below 1200 AGL.

Comment: The OP didn't ask if they wanted to know FAA or ICAO, so I threw ICAO at them. :D @casey

Comment: @SentryRaven [Oh, ICAO....](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6GMkuPiIZ2k)